# What is the correct usage of more than one Criterion

Tags: word-choice

I had the task of proof reading a technical document.
The document stated "There are two criterias and both must pass."
I suggested that the sentence should be "There are two criterion and both must pass."
Another reviewer said, "Oh no you are incorrect, just as you would say 'two cats' you should have used 'two criteria'".
It occurred to me that using the form "two criteria" could infer that we were supposed to pay attention to two sets of rules.

What would be the correct usage of criteria/criterion in this case?

Comment: "Criterion" is singular.  It's fine to use criterion to mean a benchmark, so use the plural, which you have right -- "criteria."  I'm not sure about using "cats" and "criteria" in the same sentence, though.

Comment: Generally the use of more than one criterion at a time is discouraged for criterial beginners. If you want to try another criterion, you have to put the one you're using back in the criterion rack.

Comment: That's so funny ha ha @deadrat - what, you got something against cats?

Comment: The wording of the rest of the sentence sounds a bit off to me, actually: something like "The [process] must meet two criteria to pass" or "In order to pass, the process must meet two criteria" sounds more natural to me.

Comment: Not at all, @Little Eva.  I asked my two if it was proper grammar to use "cats" and "criteria" in the same sentence, and they gave me that look.

Comment: OK @deadrat, because mine was reading your comment over my shoulder and ... well, you know.

Comment: My older cat just urped on the whole issue. :-/

Comment: @JohnLawler My first thought was the same as yours. If there are two of them, how can they be criteria? 'The essence of a criterion is that it is key to a determination', thought I. However Oxford Dictionaries Online provide this as a sample sentence *They award a green label to products that meet certain environmental criteria*. So it seems you can have more than one out at the same time.

Comment: @WS2 Suppose you don't give a thought to cats, except maybe gray, short-hair, and male-neutered. There you have three criteria.

Comment: Criteria are the same as boundary conditions for a PDE.

Comment: @JohnLawler Partial Differential Equation? Principle of double Effect????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "**criteria**".

Explanation:

Criterion = singular. Criteria = plural. "Criterias" is not standardly used at all.

It's as simple as that. The other reviewer's analogy of "criterion/criteria" with "cat/cats" is correct.

"Two sets of criteria" is what would imply two sets of rules.